# FileSystemWatcher: max number of folders

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I have a server where my app is using FileSystemWatcher to monitor a folder say, **e:\A**.
Inside the folder A, there are as many as 16,000 folders and each subfolder has numerous other folders and files.

The app is crashing to desktop in about 1 hour.
When there were fewer folders, the app was working fine.
I have increased the internal buffer to twice the default value.

Is there a limit on the maximum number of folders to be monitored?
Or the folder itself is unstable due to the huge number of folders?

**Update:**
The app runs on a virtual machine(vmware).
Windows Server 2008.
dual 2.53 Intel Xeon.
4 GB of RAM.
RAID. [ 1.3TB, may be increased. ]

Comment: "Crashing" = Throwing an exception? Just disappearing into the ether? Something else?

Comment: this will help you understand better why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195317/what-are-practical-limits-on-the-number-of-filesystemwatcher-instances-a-server

Comment: @lc. its one of those APPCRASH thing where is says "The app has stopped working" and you get to select whether to check an online solution or to close the window.

Comment: @Hardrada: thanks for pointing that out. If I have to send something to the gallows, I'd send Paged/Non-paged Pools. Still not sure..

Comment: Certainly, you don't want one FSW watching all that you have. Trim it down by either having more FSW's (1 per folder? 1 per set of folders?). Don't watch sub folders and only listen for events that you need to. I am doing something similar to this and short of writing a File System Driver, this is working out for me with a low mem foot print. But the FSW can be bitchy with network drops on UNC's.