# Is there a limit to the number of FileWatchers supported by .NET

Tags: c#, caching

Is there a limit to the number of `FileWatchers` supported by .NET, whether it be best performance practice or an actual windows limit?

I'm using the .NET [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.runtime.caching.memorycache) class to cache of a library of some 15 000 small files. Each time a file is accessed, it's cached and I understand that the `.NET MemoryCache` (via `CacheItemPolicy.ChangeMonitors`) will create some sort of file watcher on it...

More info on the [HostFileChangeMonitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.runtime.caching.hostfilechangemonitor) created

> When the HostFileChangeMonitor class is used in a non-ASP.NET application, the FileSystemWatcher class is used internally to monitor files. As a result, whatever access control list (ACL) applies to a monitored file or directory is applied to the Windows identity of the current thread.

Comment: I may be ignorant, but where does it say in the `MemoryCache` documentation that a `FileWatcher` is added to watch items in the cache?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are practical limits on the number of FileSystemWatcher instances a server can handle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195317/what-are-practical-limits-on-the-number-of-filesystemwatcher-instances-a-server)

Comment: I edited the question and will check the other question linked. Thanks.