# FileWatcher issue

Tags: c#, file-watcher

OK, so this time I created a service with a file watcher to process file once created.

it seems that my service crashes when the files being processed reaches 1000 (I'm receiving loads of messages).

here is my logic: files comes in, file watcher read the text send it to email, insert into DB, move original message to a folders.

on the service start, I'm processing pending messages first before start to watch (I'm talking about over 1000 of text file pending) and my service needs about a second to work on each file.

All goes OK, but when the total incoming files reaches 1000, it simply crash.
sometimes the service stops processing pending and only start looking for new files only.

I have the "InternalBufferSize = 64000" the max recommended.

Please help me with my code (I know it should be multi-threaded for better handling, but I'm not that expert):

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        using(TREEEntities TEX = new TREEEntities())
        {
         var mp= TEX.TREE_settings.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.SET_key =="MSGDump");
         MsgsPath = mp.SET_value;
         var dc = TEX.TREE_settings.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SET_key == "DupCash");
         DupCash = Convert.ToInt16(dc.SET_value);
        }
        if (Directory.Exists(MsgsPath))
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(MsgsPath+"\\Archive"))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(MsgsPath+"\\Archive");
            }
            if (!Directory.Exists(MsgsPath + "\\Duplicates"))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(MsgsPath + "\\Duplicates");
            }
            if (!Directory.Exists(MsgsPath + "\\Unsent"))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(MsgsPath + "\\Unsent");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(MsgsPath);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(MsgsPath + "\\Archive");
            Directory.CreateDirectory(MsgsPath + "\\Duplicates");
            Directory.CreateDirectory(MsgsPath + "\\Unsent");
        }         

        processPending();//<--- process pending files after last service stop
        fileSystemWatcher1.Path = MsgsPath;//<--- path to be watched  
        fileSystemWatcher1.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        fileSystemWatcher1.InternalBufferSize = 64000;
        addToLog(DateTime.Now, "Service Started", 0, "Service", "Info");
        addToLog(DateTime.Now, "File Watcher Started", 0, "Service", "Info");
        //dupList.Clear();//<--- clear duplicates validation list
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        fileSystemWatcher1.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        addToLog(DateTime.Now, "File Watcher Stopped", 0, "Service", "Alert");
        addToLog(DateTime.Now, "Service Stopped", 0, "Service", "Alert");
    }



    private void fileSystemWatcher1_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {             
        try
        {
            //---------read from file------------
            Thread.Sleep(200);//<---give the file some time to get released
            string block;
            using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(MsgsPath + "\\" + e.Name))
            {
                block = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
            PRT = block.Substring(block.Length - 6, 6);//<--- get the printer name
            seq = Convert.ToInt16(block.Substring(block.Length - 20, 20).Substring(0, 4));//<--- get the sequence number
            switch (PRT)//<----track sequence number from the 3 printers
            {
                case "64261B"://<---prt1
                    int seqPlus1=0;
                    if(seqPrt1 == 9999)//<---ignore sequence change from 9999 to 1
                    { seqPlus1 = 1; }
                    else { seqPlus1 = seqPrt1 + 1; }                         
                    if (seq != seqPlus1 && seqPrt1 != 0)//<---"0" to avoid first service start
                    {
                        int x = seq - seqPrt1 - 1;
                        for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++)
                        {
                            addToMissing(PRT, seqPlus1);
                            addToLog(DateTime.Now, "Missing Sequence Number On Printer: " + PRT + " - " + seqPlus1, seqPlus1, "Service", "Missing");
                            seqPlus1++;
                        }                           
                        seqPrt1 = seq;
                    }
                    else { seqPrt1 = seq; }
                    break;
                case "24E9AA"://<---prt2
                    int seqPlus2=0;
                    if(seqPrt2 == 9999)
                    { seqPlus2 = 1; }
                    if (seq != seqPlus2 && seqPrt2 != 0)
                    {
                        int x = seq - seqPrt2 - 1;
                        for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++)
                        {
                            addToMissing(PRT, seqPlus2);
                            addToLog(DateTime.Now, "Missing Sequence Number On Printer: " + PRT + " - " + seqPlus2, seqPlus2, "Service", "Missing");
                            seqPlus2++;
                        }                          
                        seqPrt2 = seq;
                    }
                    else { seqPrt2 = seq; }
                    break;
                case "642602"://<---prt3
                    int seqPlus3=0;
                    if(seqPrt3 == 9999)
                    { seqPlus3 = 1; }
                    if (seq != seqPlus3 && seqPrt3 != 0)
                    {
                        int x = seq - seqPrt3 - 1;
                        for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++)
                        {
                            addToMissing(PRT, seqPlus3);
                            addToLog(DateTime.Now, "Missing Sequence Number On Printer: " + PRT + " - " + seqPlus3, seqPlus3, "Service", "Missing");
                            seqPlus3++;
                        }                      
                        seqPrt3 = seq;
                    }
                    else { seqPrt3 = seq; }
                    break;
            }
            block = block.Remove(block.Length - 52);//<--- trim the sequence number and unwanted info
            string[] Alladd;
            List<string> sent = new List<string>();
            if (!dupList.Contains(block)) //<--- if msg not found in duplicates validation list
            {
                //--------extract values--------------
                if (block.Substring(0, 3) == "\r\nQ") //<--- if the msg. contains a priority code
                {
                    Alladd = block.Substring(0, block.IndexOf(".")).Replace("\r\n", " ").Substring(4).Split(' ').Distinct().Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray(); ;
                }
                else//<--- if no priority code
                {
                    Alladd = block.Substring(0, block.IndexOf(".")).Replace("\r\n", " ").Substring(1).Split(' ').Distinct().Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray(); ;
                }
                string From = block.Substring(block.IndexOf('.') + 1).Substring(0, 7);
                string Msg = block.Substring(block.IndexOf('.') + 1);
                Msg = Msg.Substring(Msg.IndexOf('\n') + 1);

                //--------add msg content to the DB group table--------
                using (TREEEntities TE1 = new TREEEntities())
                {
                    TREE_group tg = new TREE_group()
                    {
                        GROUP_original = block,
                        GROUP_sent = Msg,
                        GROUP_dateTime = DateTime.Now,
                        GROUP_from = From,
                        GROUP_seq = seq,
                        GROUP_prt = PRT,
                    };
                    TE1.AddToTREE_group(tg);
                    TE1.SaveChanges();
                    GID = tg.GROUP_ID;
                }
                //--------validate addresses---------------
                foreach (string TB in Alladd)
                {
                    string email = "";
                    string typeB = "";
                    TREEEntities TE = new TREEEntities();
                    var q1 = from x in TE.TREE_users where x.USR_TypeB == TB && x.USR_flag == "act" select new { x.USR_email, x.USR_TypeB };
                    foreach (var itm in q1)
                    {
                        email = itm.USR_email;
                        typeB = itm.USR_TypeB;
                    }

                    //-------send mail if the user exist----                  
                    if (TB == typeB)
                    {
                        if (typeB == "BAHMVGF")
                        {
                            addToFtl(block);
                        }
                        try
                        {
                            sendMail SM = new sendMail();
                            SM.SendMail(Msg, "Message from: " + From, email);
                            //---save record in DB----
                            addToMsg(typeB, email,"sent","act",1,GID,seq);                               
                            sent.Add(typeB);
                        }
                        catch (Exception x)
                        {
                            addToMsg(typeB, email, "Failed", "act", 1, GID, seq);                              
                            addToLog(DateTime.Now, "Send message failed: " + x.Message, GID, "Service", "Warning");
                        }
                    }
                    //-------if no user exist----
                    else
                    {
                        if (TB == "BAHMVGF")
                        {
                            addToFtl(block);
                        }
                        addToMsg(TB, "No email", "Failed", "act", 1, GID, seq);                          
                        addToLog(DateTime.Now, "Send message failed, unknown Type-B address: " + TB, GID, "Service", "Warning");
                    }
                }

                if (sent.Count < Alladd.Count())//<--- if there is unsent addresses
                {
                    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(block);
                    foreach (string add in sent)
                    {
                        b.Replace(add, "");//<--- remove address that has been sent from the original message and write new msg. to unsent folder
                    }
                    if (!Directory.Exists(MsgsPath + "\\Unsent"))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(MsgsPath + "\\Unsent");
                    }
                    using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(MsgsPath + "\\Unsent\\" + e.Name))
                    {
                        w.WriteLine(b);
                    }
                }
                sent.Clear();
                //---add to dupList to validate the next messages-------------
                if (dupList.Count > DupCash)
                {
                    dupList.RemoveAt(0);
                }
                dupList.Add(block);
                //---move msg to archive folder-----------------     
                if (!Directory.Exists(MsgsPath + "\\Archive"))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(MsgsPath + "\\Archive");
                }
                File.Move(MsgsPath + "\\" + e.Name, MsgsPath + "\\Archive\\" + e.Name);
            }

            else //<--- if message is a duplicate
            {
                addToLog(DateTime.Now, "Duplicated message, message not sent", seq, "Service", "Info");
                //---move msg to duplicates folder-----------------  
                if (!Directory.Exists(MsgsPath + "\\Duplicates"))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(MsgsPath + "\\Duplicates");
                }
                File.Move(MsgsPath + "\\" + e.Name, MsgsPath + "\\Duplicates\\" + e.Name);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            addToLog(DateTime.Now, "Error: " + x.Message, seq, "Service", "Alert");
            if (!Directory.Exists(MsgsPath + "\\Unsent"))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(MsgsPath + "\\Unsent");
            }
            //---move msg to Unsent folder-----------------                    
            File.Move(MsgsPath + "\\" + e.Name, MsgsPath + "\\Unsent\\" + e.Name);
        }

    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195317/what-are-practical-limits-on-the-number-of-filesystemwatcher-instances-a-server

Comment: Would increasing the buffer size helps?  I have all of the files locally (dedicated server) not on a shared network.

Comment: If you want help and you think this isn't a duplicate of the previously referenced Q&A, you need to be more specific than just "it crashes".

Comment: I get this on the event viewer: "windows service terminated unexpectedly"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to add this as a comment but it exceeded the allowed number of characters so here goes.

First thing I noticed in your code that you are doing all the file handling inside the Created event handler. This is not a good practice, you should always let your FileSystemWatcher event handlers do minimum work as it might result an overflow which is probably what you are facing.
Instead it is better to delegate the work on a separate thread. You can add the events to a queue and let a background thread worry handling them. You can filter the files in the event handler so that your queue does not get filled with garbage.

Using Sleep inside the event handler is also considered a bad practice as you'll be blocking the FileSystemWatcher event.

The maximum buffer size allowed is 64K, it is not a recommended buffer size unless you are dealing with long paths. Increasing buffer size is expensive, because it comes from non-paged memory that cannot be swapped out to disk, so keep the buffer as small as possible. To avoid a buffer overflow, use the [NotifyFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.notifyfilter(v=vs.110).aspx) and [IncludeSubdirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.includesubdirectories(v=vs.110).aspx) properties to filter out unwanted change notifications.

And finally I would suggest reading the FileSystemWatcher [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and looking at several examples online before attempting to write code as the Windows watcher is somewhat delicate and prone to errors

Comment: You could split into multiple comments.

Comment: @tbodt no need to be a wise guy, the answer is valid. I would suggest you also read the MSDN article.