# Using FileSystemWatcher on DataOntap

Tags: filesystemwatcher, readdirectorychangesw, netapp

I have a project that watches file creation/deletion activity on a network share which is currently hosted by a Windows Server machine, but I'm considering moving the files to a NetApp box running DataOntap. Their API documentation says they support ReadDirectoryChangesW, which is what FileSystemWatcher is using below the covers, but I'm concerned that it might not be a full implementation. Are there any pitfalls I should watch out for?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know specifically about NetApp and DataOntap, but see this other question and its various answers:

[FileSystemWatcher and windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250343/filesystemwatcher-and-windows-7)

It seems that people have been having a lot of trouble with FileSystemWatcher, particularly when used with a network share.